# How can I increase text size of android chronometer?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have created chronometer programatically.But i don't know how to increase size of chronometer text.following is my code.I have set the initial value 00:00 but this text looking small i want to increase size of that.
Please Help.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


         LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
         layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
         flag="false";
         prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
                  "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
         mChronometer = new Chronometer(this);



         // Set the initial value
         mChronometer.setText("00:00");
         layout.addView(mChronometer);

         Button startButton = new Button(this);
         startButton.setText("Start");
         startButton.setOnClickListener(mStartListener);
         layout.addView(startButton);

         Button stopButton = new Button(this);
         stopButton.setText("Stop");
         stopButton.setOnClickListener(mStopListener);
         layout.addView(stopButton);

         Button resetButton = new Button(this);
         resetButton.setText("Reset");
         resetButton.setOnClickListener(mResetListener);
         layout.addView(resetButton);        

         setContentView(layout);
     }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chronometer extends TextView, so what about

```
mChronometer.setTextSize(size);
```

Comment: ohhhh thanks Keshav for answering my foolish question